# How to define repositories for all subprojects in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build-script

I am writing Gradle scripts to build a lot of projects. They are using the same repositories so I would like to define repositories for all of my sub-projects instead of defining in each of them. 
So I try to move the repositories definition from the build.gradle in an individual project into the build.gradle in their parent folder.

```
subprojects{
    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir{
            name 'uploadRepository'
            dirs '../../sharedlib'
        }
    }
}
```

However, the sub-projects can't find the repository definition at all. Moving other configurations in subprojects closure work. I've tried dependencies and properties configuration. They all work with no problem. I don't know why repositories work differently. 
When Googling, I can't find any example of putting repositories inside subprojects, I suspect I am doing it the wrong way. Please tell me what's wrong. 
Thanks!

Comment: "However, the sub-projects can't find the repository definition at all." How can you tell? Which exact effect are you seeing (which task fails, what's the error message, etc.)?

Comment: It is complaining with the following error messages:
* Where:
Build file 'F:\build_scripts\temp\build_standardization\experiments\portlets\TFANetRegions\build.gradle' line: 69

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'TFANetRegions'.
> Could not find property 'uploadRepository' on repository container.

Comment: I put the settings.gradle in the parent project which include my subproject. This makes Gradle able to find the repositories. However, now it can't find the dependencies and properties setting (sourceCompatibility=1.5). This wasn't a problem when settings.gradle wasn't there. Now I am confused what the settings.gradle actually does.

Comment: Check out the multi-project builds chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what the problem was. 
Originally, I missed the settings.gradle in the parent folder. (I don't know why dependencies configuration works even without this file)
After I put that in, the sub-projects could find the repositories, but the dependencies and an one property (sourceCompatibility=1.5) I defined in the parent project no longer works. 
I have to move the apply plugin:'war' from the subproject's build.gradle to the parent's subprojects{...}
I figure that's because the dependencies and sourceCompatibility are things provided by the plugin. And somehow Gradle doesn't look into the subproject's script to find the plugin first.

Answer (score 0):

Your repository declarations look fine, except that an upload repository isn't declared in the `project.repositories` block but inside the upload task (e.g. `uploadArchives`). The [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) has the details.